# How can I use cURL to get data from php page

Tags: curl

I'm trying to work with an API and I think cURL would be my best option for getting this data.  I want to be able to extract bits of data from this page 
https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker

Comment: Which specific bits of data do you want to extract?

Comment: You see, this site is not about what you want but to help you understand why things happen the way they do when you need.

Comment: For Example if I wanted to grab the value after "last" and maybe Values after "high" and "low"

Answer (score 0):

You could use perl to parse the json data, then feed perl with curl:

```
curl -s 'https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker' | \
perl -e '
    use JSON;
    $s = join("", <>);
    $j = decode_json($s);
    printf "%s\n", $j->{"ticker"}{"vol"};
'
```

Replace "vol" with any of the others you may be interested in:
"vol_cur", "avg", "last", "sell", "buy", "high", "server_time", "low", "updated"

Or you could use curl inside perl:

```
perl -e '
    use JSON;
    $j = decode_json(`curl -s https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker`);
    printf "%s\n", $j->{"ticker"}{"vol"};
'
```

Answer (score 0):

With [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) and [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) ([javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)) :

```
nodejs <<EOF
var x = $(curl -s https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker)
console.log('$'+x.ticker.high)
EOF
```

Output :

```
$9.4504
```

Another solution using [rhino](/questions/tagged/rhino) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

```
rhino <<EOF
var x = $(curl -s https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker)
print(x.ticker.high)
EOF
```